# Delete woocommerce products associated to categories

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I have deleted all the products from my store using these query:

```
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id IN 
(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN 
('product','product_variation'));
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation');
```

Then I ran this to delete orphaned postmeta:

```
DELETE pm
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id[![enter image description here][1]][1]
WHERE wp.ID IS NULL
```

Even though all the products were delete I still have products associated to the categories:

[image]

I don't want to delete the categories (because it would destroy the vast menu on the website that I have built). I just want to delete the products associated to the categories.

So what I would like to achieve would be this:
[image]

How can I do that without messing up the categories itself?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In Woocommerce > status > tools you can force the terms re-count

Comment: Awesome. It solved the problem. Thank you so much @LoicTheAztec!